# Converting html entities to HTML text

Tags: php, html, html-entities

I have this string:

```
&amp;lt;p&amp;gt;This is a test&amp;lt;/p&amp;gt;rn&amp;lt;p&amp;gt;&amp;lt;strong&amp;gt;this is a test&amp;lt;/strong&amp;gt;&amp;lt;/p&amp;gt;
```

So I'm trying to convert the original string to HTML.

I've tried:

```
echo ' <h4><b>Din besvarelse</b></h4> 
<text style="word-wrap: break-word; height:auto;">
'.htmlspecialchars_decode($progressinfo['comment']).'</text>';
```

which converts the entity to normal HTML but it prints out the raw html..

```
&lt;p&gt;This is a test&lt;/p&gt;rn&lt;p&gt;&lt;strong&gt;this is a test&lt;/strong&gt;&lt;/p&gt;
```

I want to it be like this:

```
<p>This is a test</p>rn<p><strong>this is a test</strong></p>
```

So how do I convert a string containing HTML entities to raw HTML to be rendered in HTML?

Thanks

Comment: working at my end:- http://prntscr.com/cp011f. Or i am missing something?

Comment: I don't see any difference between the "it prints out the raw html" [] and what you show you "want it to be like this".  I'm not seeing any difference there, dude.

Comment: @chris85 This is what I get:
https://i.gyazo.com/ee7dd46c892cc2e7bb225936b7823a11.png

I want the HTML to also work, not only be printed out

Comment: @anant I want the HTML to work also.. see comment above

Comment: @chris85 Thank you so much! I have tried so many solutions. You made my day

Answer (score 2):

`&amp;lt;` is a double encoded element. Using `htmlspecialchars_decode` once gets it to `&lt;` because `&amp;` is converted to `&`. The browser then renders that as `<`, not as an element. Use the function twice and it will be rendered as HTML.

```
echo htmlspecialchars_decode(htmlspecialchars_decode('&amp;lt;p&amp;gt;This is a test&amp;lt;/p&amp;gt;rn&amp;lt;p&amp;gt;&amp;lt;strong&amp;gt;this is a test&amp;lt;/strong&amp;gt;&amp;lt;/p&amp;gt;'));
```

Demo: https://eval.in/653807